# How to skip mysql table update if previous row is identical based on certain columns

Tags: mysql

I'm inserting data into a mysql table via a php script, however I wanted to know if there is a better way to insert data if the previous row is not identical.

For example:

```
Stock Price  Bid    Ask    Timestamp
AAPL 232.23  232.22 232.23 1879239289
TSLA 500.23  500.12 500.26 1879239346
```

If the next record for aapl is identical to the most recent record of aapl.  I don't want to insert it.

Likewise with TSLA.

I know I can do a query before insert, sort by id desc, and check each column - but is there another way using mysql trigger or condition?

Comment: Normally we make a unique index on the columns that define "the same as another row", but does "next" mean literally "the (and only the) subsequently inserted row" ? i.e. is it permitted to have 3 AAPL rows of `1,1,1,1` `2,2,2,2` and then `1,1,1,3` - the third row of 1,1,1 not being a duplicate of the first 1,1,1 because there is an interim 2,2,2?

Comment: Specifically only if the previous record was identical based on ticker. If another one prevoiusly is identical, (not including timestamp for these) are same its ok.  Its literally the last one with the same ticker which has the same price, bid and ask.

Comment: I'd put it in as a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Make the ID as primary key in MySQL and into the php code create the query between try catch.
https://stackify.com/php-try-catch-php-exception-tutorial/